# Colour a cell based on the colours applied to a key list

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to apply the colours in a list to an array of cells.  The list contains the items that are made available in a data validation drop-down for each cell. [This example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WIAZUREzxlXxRJz_feS75mAh2xmwd7qNbUEWJj0aM6I/edit?usp=sharing) should show what I mean. I have manually set the backgrounds of the cells to match the key but I want to do this automatically, so that when a cell is assigned from a drop-down it gets the colour from the key table.

Can this be done with conditional formatting (bearing in mind that the key list will get new members/colours)?

Answer (score 1):

No. But the whole range (table and dropdown cells) can be formatted with CF formula rules (one per colour).

Comment: Yes, but in the general case, where items are added to the key table, I was wanting to avoid the manual step of adding another CF rule each time I added to the list.  So it looks like a script solution is required with an `onChange` event trigger.